# HashMap<K,V>.entry() erroring with `undeclared type 'Entry'`

Tags: rust

I'm trying to add a value to `Vec<String>` in a `HashMap<String, Vec<String>>` when the key exists and create a new entry when it doesn't.  I'm following the documentation on this as best I can but still getting this error:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type `Entry`
```

For the following code:

```
use std::collections::HashMap; 
fn main() {
    let mut dir: HashMap<String, Vec<String>> = HashMap::new();
    let group = String::from("Sales");
    let emp = String::from("Bob");
    
    match dir.entry(group) {
        Entry::Vacant(e) => e.insert(vec![emp]),
        Entry::Occupied(mut e) => e.get_mut().push(emp)
    }
    
    println!("{:?}", dir)
}
```

Comment: `use std::collections::hash_map::*; `

Answer (score 4):

A type must be in scope before you can refer to it. You therefore must add a `use` declaration for `std::collections::hash_map::Entry`, or fully qualify it everytime you write it.